# !! Solved !! Why does mdadm --create start recovery

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

**!! Solved !!**

Hi there i'm trying to create a md software RAID5.

First some info
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy

```
mdadm - v4.1 - 2018-10-01
```

The command works fine:

```
 mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

But for some reason it starts a recovery that will approx. take 1½ hour or so.
I can see that by doing a cat /proc/mdstat.
The disks is brand new.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

Yes offcourse it is normal.
Since the md subsystem dosn't have a filesystem, it has to rebuild checksums for the entire array.